# Prevent horizontal scrolling with javascript?

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know if there is a way to prevent the user from being able to scroll horizontally? ive used overflow-x:hidden css, but it can still sometimes scroll (but only sometimes, its weird..)

http://www.kaiserroof.com

Would it be possible to disable keystroke events for right/left arrows as well as left/right mousewheel with javascript?  if there is no horizontal scrolling, they wouldnt need those buttons anyway.  I thought there was a way to do this with javascript, but i cant remember? like onkeypress "left arrow" return false?  i dont know too much javascript though..

Comment: It looks like you've got some improperly-nested tags or something. By the way, that piercing noise you have on mouse over of the links is one of the worst things I have ever seen. You should remove it, nobody wants a website that hurts your ears.

Comment: Can you scroll horizontally when the vertical scroll bar appears?

Comment: notjim - yeah i hate that noise too but thats what the client wanted.
rmarimon - im not sure i understand your quesion.

Comment: On my Chrome browser, there's no horiz scroll for your site, but as a result I could not see the entire width of your page unless I resized the browser. And for people with regular sized screens (I have a large size, heh), that may not be an option.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you put `overflow-x: hidden` in the HTML body; however this will not work. Use `overflow-x: hidden` on the element that you wish to disable horizontal scrolling.

Comment: He means `owerflow-x: hidden;`.

Comment: Or maybe `överflow-x: hidden`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with jquery if anyone wants to know:

```
<script language="JavaScript"><!--
function checkKey(e){
     switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            return false;
            break;
        case 39:
            return false;
            break;
        default:
            return true;  
            }      
}

if ($.browser.mozilla) {
    $(document).keypress (checkKey);
} else {
    $(document).keydown (checkKey);
}
--></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this workaround

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(evt) {
var height = $(window).scrollTop();
scrollTo(0,height);
});
```

See my bin [here](http://jsbin.com/iTODEsOR/10/edit)